# HMAccessoryDelegates not calling on Button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, homekit, ios-homekit

I am working on Homekit iOS app. I have a question that I have an accessory and When I change its power characteristic value using the HomeKit Simulator the delegates of HMAccessory are caliing but in case If I change the powr characteristic value programmatically (Using the writevalue ) the delegate methods are not being called. Please let me know any ideas of suggestions.

```
Code 

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    selectedDevice.delegate = self;
}
```

**HMAccessoryDelegate**

```
- (void)accessory:(HMAccessory *)accessory service:(HMService *)service didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(HMCharacteristic *)characteristic;
{
    NSLog(@"changed");
}
```

**Write Function**

```
UISwitch *sw = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 5, 51, 31)];
[cell addSubview:sw];
sw.on = YES;
[sw addTarget:self action:@selector(updateState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

-(void)updateState:(UISwitch*)sender
{
HMCharacteristic *characteristic = self.selectedService.characteristics[tag];

[characteristic enableNotification:YES completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
             {
                 if(!error)
                 {

                 }
             }];
 if([characteristic.characteristicType isEqualToString:HMCharacteristicTypePowerState])
        {
        id val = characteristic.value;
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",val];

        if([str isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            id a = characteristic.value;

            BOOL b = [a boolValue];

            NSNumber *c = [NSNumber numberWithBool:!b];

            AppDelegate *appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

            [characteristic writeValue:c completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    UIAlertView *alertController = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[appDel handleErrorCodes:error.code] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                    [alertController show];
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    [serviceCharacteristicsTableView reloadData];
                }
            }];

        }
}
```

Please let me know if I am not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HomeKit/Reference/HMAccessoryDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/HMAccessoryDelegate/accessory:service:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:) says that the delegate method is not called when you set the value programatically:

> This method is called as a result of a change in value initiated by
>   the accessory. Programmatic changes initiated by the app do not result
>   in this method being called.

If you want to do something after writing the characteristic's value succeeded (or failed), you can do it in the `completionHandler:` block of  `writeValue:completionHandler:` method.